# Tracking down error on form or in session

Tags: asp-classic

Apologies if this is classic ASP 101, but its been so long since I did any ASP Im struggling to understand / track this error down. What makes it worse is Ive inherited this application and I cant ask the original author..

I have a shopping cart that includes an input checkbox and numerous other fields. When the form is processed and submitted it is run through some javascript and then if all is ok, redirected to another page. (Nothing unusual there). Firebug shows that at this point the value of the check box is different depending on its checked state.

When the form is submitted it goes to another page that iterates over the session.Contents() collection, and builds up a string that is sent to a 3rd party. Using fiddler, it appears that whilst the name of the checkBox is in this string, the value is always 'on'

From reading Google, I see that the session.Contents collection is all parameters that have been placed in the session / application. but a grep across all the files in the project directory doesnt turn up anywhere that the checkbox is added to the session.

So, is the cb there simply because it is on the form or used in javascript, or are there other ways of adding the variable into the session. (Grep on the name doesnt turn up any other instances).

And secondly, if the variable is in the session, no matter how it got there, why is it always set to "on". Im assuming that somehow it has been added to the session and set to On before the form is processed. But the checkbox defaults to unchecked, so Im confused!

Can anyone help explain this, or even suggest how I can track it down / fix it. (The obvious answer is to try to force it into the session with the correct value, but I'd like to know why it is misbehaving rather than just ignore it in case I meet something like this again!

Thanks

Comment: Checkboxes work with ASP.  If it is not clearing then you will need to do some tracing to see what is happening.  I can't be more specific without seeing the code.  If the form is passing values thru the querystring then perhaps the page is being cached ???

Comment: There are other values that are being passed correctly, so I dont think that its a cache issue.

I'll have to dig out a primer on ASP debugging and try to see whats happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that you have already determined that the JavaScript is not modifying checkbox state priort to allowing the submission.

When your form is submitted, the fields that are submitted are in the Request.Form collection. When a checkbox is not checked, it is not part of the Request.Form collection. Therefore, there will be as many checkbox fields in your Request.Form collection as you had checked when submitting, and they will all have the value of their respective "value" property.

If you then add these to the Session.Contents collection, they persist until the session ends. If you never explicitly clear the Session.Contents collection, but submit the form more than once with different values, then the Session.Contents collection will continue to accrue more and more (checkbox_name, checkbox_value) pairs until such time as it contains a (checkbox_name, checkbox_value) pair for every checkbox on your form.

You may wish to write a function that clears each one of your form fields from the session, and call this either after processing a form, or before processing a form (whichever makes sense for your application). Alternatively, just use the Request.Form collection.

Comment: I will try this today. What you are saying makes sense, if I Grep the application for code that adds to the session, or removes items from it I find very little. Certainly nothing thats clearing items out unless they are explicitly removed via the web page.
I'll be bac later Im sure to mark as answered.
Thanks